# getting error "Could not load definitions from resource" while running ant build

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy, ant

I am not getting the above error when I am running the ANT file through batch script. But when I run it though groovy I am facing the error.

'''taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"

taskdef resource="com/oracle/calcmgr/anttask/antcontrib.properties"'''

Any one kindly help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins *(and jenkins slave)* have their own Tool installation.
You should check your **Ant** installation path, as "antcontrib" is not part of default distribution, and must be manually provided into "\lib" directory.

`Jenkins > Configure > Tools`

Hope this helps
Regards